# Lowering the spacetime index of a Dirac matrix

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, notation, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

$\gamma_\mu\partial^\mu$=$\gamma^\nu\partial_\nu$

Does the above equation hold for Gamma matrices? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. You simply define $\gamma_\nu = \eta_{\mu\nu} \gamma^\mu$, $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ being the Minkowski metric, and you have $\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu = \gamma^\mu \eta_{\mu\nu} \eta^{\nu\sigma} \partial_\sigma = \gamma_\nu \partial^\nu$, where I employed $\delta_\mu {}^\sigma = \eta_{\mu\nu} \eta^{\nu\sigma}$.